# Python regex checking length of the string for two discrete values

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to check a string for a pattern which its length can be either 3 or 6; not the values between them.

This is the string:

```
color: #FfFdF8; background-color:#aef;
```

I want to get all sub-strings starting with `#` followed by a hex code, if they have the length of 3 or 6 and are not located at the beginning of the string; in this case both `#FfFdF8` and `#aef` should be returned.

I have written this pattern:

```
r'^(?!#).+(#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}).*|^(?!#).+(#[a-fA-F0-9]{3}).*'
```

But it gave me `[('#FfFdF8', '')]` as the result of `re.findall`.

Comment: `if not s.startswith('#'): results = re.findall(r'#[a-fA-F0-9]{3}(?:[a-fA-F0-9]{3})?\b', s)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, it worked. Thanks. Would you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may first check if the string starts with `#` and if not, extract the `#...` substrings:

```
import re
results = []
s = 'color: #FfFdF8; background-color:#aef;'
if not s.startswith('#'): 
    results = re.findall(r'#[a-fA-F0-9]{3}(?:[a-fA-F0-9]{3})?\b', s)
print(results) # => ['#FfFdF8', '#aef']
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9FUCwJ/1) and the [Python demo](https://rextester.com/PHAJN95582).

**Regex details**

- `#` - a `#` char
- `[a-fA-F0-9]{3}` - 3 hex chars
- `(?:[a-fA-F0-9]{3})?` - an optional sequence of three hex chars
- `\b` - a word boundary (no more hex chars to the right are allowed)